# Irreducibility of a cubic in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> **Problem**
>
> Show that $$X^3-2008X^2+2010X-2009$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

**Progress**

I considered applying Eisenstein's Theorem, but there are no primes $p$ such that $p|2008$, $p|2009$ and $p|2010$. (This is quite clear as $\nexists p$ prime such that p divides consecutive integers for any choice of p.)

I think this may require an application of Gauss's Lemma, but I'm yet to successfully show it. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $ By Gauss's lemma if $\rm\:f(x)\:$ splits over $\rm\:\mathbb Q\:$ then it splits over $\rm\:\mathbb Z\:,\:$ hence it splits over $\rm\:\mathbb Z/3\:,\:$ contra $\rm\ f(x)\ \equiv\ x^3-x^2+1\ $ has no roots $\rm\ mod\ 3\:.$

**REMARK** $\ $ Gauss's Lemma is a bit overkill here. But it's trivial to prove the simple monic case:

**LEMMA** $\rm\ \ f\ g\in \mathbb Z[x]\ \Rightarrow\ g \in \mathbb Z[x]\ \ \ if\ \ \ g\in \mathbb Q[x],\ \ monic\ f\in \mathbb Z[x]$

**Proof** $\ $ Write $\rm\ g = c\ x^n + g'\:,\  \ deg\ g' < deg\ g = n\:.\ $ Since $\rm\:f\:g \in \mathbb Z[x]\:$ its lead coeff $\rm\:c\in\mathbb Z\:.\:$ Thus $\rm\:f\ g' =\: f\ g - c\ x^n\:f\: \in\: \mathbb Z[x]\:,\:$ so $\rm\:g'\in \mathbb Z[x]\:$ by induction on deg $\rm\:g\:,\:$ so $\rm\ g = c\ x^n + g'\in \mathbb Z[x]\:.\:  $ **QED**

Comment: Hadn't thought about applying splitting fields in this way; thanks!

Comment: @TJO Above "f splits" means f $\ne 0$ is reducible, i.e. it "splits" into a product of two nonunit factors. No knowledge of splitting fields is employed.

Answer (score 7):

Since the polynomial is a cubic, if it can be nontrivially factored, then one of the factors must be linear. So it suffices to show that the polynomial does not have rational roots. From the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), any rational root must also be an integer. Moreover, it must be a divisor of $2009$, i.e., one of $\{ 1,  7,  41, 49, 287, 2009 \}$. [We can rule out the negative numbers because the polynomial is strictly negative for $X < 0$.] Therefore, to prove that the polynomial is irreducible, it suffices to check none of these $6$ numbers is a root of the polynomial.

Comment: Does the proposed method require factoring $2009$ or did you have something simpler in mind? I cannot tell from the hint. No factorization is needed if you work mod $3$, as I hinted.

Comment: @Bill, Yes, you're right. I had factoring $2009$ in mind, nothing simpler.